# Download zip in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, firefox, download, zip

I am using this code in agularjs to download .zip, the problem is that in Chrome if you download it in firefox it does not show me the save window.

I leave code

```
ServicioWeb.getDocumentoDictamen(x).then(
    function (data, status, headers, config) {
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        var blob = new Blob([data.data], { type: "application/zip" });
        var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        FuncionesGlobales.Loading('hide');
        //window.open(objectUrl);       
        var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var date = new Date();
        var date1 = $filter('date')(date, "dd-MM-yyyy");
        a.href = fileURL;
        a.download = "Dictamen_" + Iv + "_" + date1 + ".zip";
        a.click();

    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        FuncionesGlobales.Loading('hide');
        FuncionesGlobales.enviaMensaje("danger", "Hubo un problema en el servidor");
    });
```

Comment: Isn't it a browser settings option -- show Save Dialog?

Comment: I already checked it and if this configuration always asks, but still does not save it